# Does the cross country for instrument rating have leg distance requirements?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, far-61

I already have my commercial rating so I don’t need to do that long XC.

IR-Is this 250nm requirement for the total distance of the flight?

> *Sec. 61.65*
>
> *Instrument rating requirements.*
>
> (d) Aeronautical experience for the instrument-airplane rating. A
> person who applies for an instrument-airplane rating must have logged:
>
> > (ii) Instrument flight training on cross country flight procedures,
> > including one cross country flight in an airplane with an authorized
> > instructor, that is performed under instrument flight rules, when a
> > flight plan has been filed with an air traffic control facility, and
> > that involves--
>
> > > **(A) A flight of 250 nautical miles along airways or by directed routing from an air traffic control facility;**
> > >
> > > (B) An instrument approach at each airport; and
> > >
> > > (C) Three different kinds of approaches with the use of navigation
> > > systems.

Answer (score 4):

The 250NM is for the total distance of flight. However it also needs to be [long enough to fit in the definition of a cross country flight for flight training purposes](https://www.law.cornell.edu/definitions/index.php?width=840&height=800&iframe=true&def_id=eab37269650a24acdd82b32ba15187b2&term_occur=1&term_src=Title:14:Chapter:I:Subchapter:D:Part:61:Subpart:E:61.109), in other words you are going to need to fly more than 50NM from your home airport.

> (ii) For the purpose of **meeting the aeronautical experience
> requirements** (except for a rotorcraft category rating), for a private
> pilot certificate (except for a powered parachute category rating), a
> commercial pilot certificate, **or an instrument rating**, or for the
> purpose of exercising recreational pilot privileges (except in a
> rotorcraft) under § 61.101 (c), time acquired during a flight -
>
> (B) **That includes a point of landing that was at least a straight-line distance of more than 50 nautical miles from the original point of departure**